# MS Access as database

Tags: ms-access, desktop

We were planning to develop a desktop application with MS Access as DB. But we have certain doubts ?
1. When we install this application after development in client machine does it require MS Acess ?
2. If Yes, do they need to buy licence of MS Access from Microsoft or is it free ?
3. How can we conduct a check while installing the software if MS Access on the system ? If not how can we install MS Access also along with our application ?

Comment: check out [Good Free Alternative To MS Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044/good-free-alternative-to-ms-access/29057#29057)

Comment: @Vinay: In one of your comments below, you state that your Datastore requirement is "huge".  Keep in mind that Access .mdb/.accdb files have a hard limit of 2GB.  And as for storing images in your datastore, that is almost certainly a bad idea, but it is really a separate issue.

Comment: Will you be using MS Access as the front-end (ie, creating forms and reports with it) or just as your back-end datastore?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql script to create a new database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681167/sql-script-to-create-a-new-database)

Answer (score 2):

In your comments to Haz and duffymo, you indicated your intention is to store "huge size images" in the database.  That is not a best practice with MS Access.  Due to the way images are stored, the db file size will increase by more than the size of the image files.  Starting with Access 2007, there is an improved storage method which reduces that bloat, but it is still an issue.  Furthermore this could be a deal-breaker, because the absolute hard-wired file size limit for an Access db file is 2 GB ... your database might not be able to accommodate enough huge images to meet your needs.

I'm unclear about your concern over the need to install Access itself.  With recent (since Win 2000) 32-bit Windows versions, the components required to use an Access db file are included as part of the operating system.  If you're dealing with 64 bit Windows, you may need to get the [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23734)

Installing Access should only be required if your application uses Access for more than just data storage.  An application which uses Access as the front-end client (with Access forms, reports, etc.) would require some form of Access to be installed, but it needn't be the full-blown version.  You could design your application for the Access runtime version, which is free of cost starting with Access 2007:

1. [Access 2007 Download: Access Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4438)
2. [Microsoft Access 2010 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10910)

However, if you're using something else (e.g. Dot.Net) for your application front-end, you wouldn't need any form of Access installed.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever store large images in an access data base. A big database is a slow database. Use vba to check and create file paths and store the images outside of the database. Hit me up for the code to do that

Answer (score 0):

MS Access is often the cheapest way to develop a distributed database application and frankly you should have your client buy a licenses it the tool meets your requirements. I think building a desktop application from scratch is often ridiculous when you'll probably spend well over $100 of your time building features that come out of the box with MS Access. Unless you're doing this work for free, buying software or software components to help speed up delivery is always a good idea.

One caveat. Access Db files are limited to 2gb. If you have to store data that exceeds this, you'll either need to connect the Access database to a larger database or create a complex partitioning strategy.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how your software works. Do you have a program that calls the Access DB, or is your program implemented using access forms?

If your just using Access as a DB

1. No, you just require the JET runtime
2. You can find the JET runtime on the microsoft site
3. It depends on what installer package you are using. You can include the MDAC MSI as a dependency if your using a typical .NET Installer.

If your using Access for the DB and the program

1. Yes
2. Yes they need to buy it. Just like you needed to buy it to develop your database. No it's not free
3. If Access is not on their computer, they will need to purchase it, then insert the CD and complete the installation.

Comment: Hi Haz,But my Datastorage requirement is quite big, with huge size images and large amount of data..Will SQLite be good enough ?

Comment: I didn't suggest SQLLite, I suggested getting the JET installer (if your just using Access as a DB) which is free, or getting your customer to buy Access if your program is written in access too. SQLLite is only going to replace the database engine, which you don't need to do if that is the only bit in Access. If your entire application is in Access then SQLLite won't magically rewrite the code for you.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Jet runtime". Jet 4 is installed on every copy of Windows starting with Windows 2000, so you never have to install it if you're using Jet 4 as your data store. If you want to use ACCDB format, you would need to install the ACE, downloadable from Microsoft.

Comment: The Access runtime is free starting with Access 2007, so, no, you don't need to purchase Access for all your users. However, the developer *does* need a full copy of Access, and that has to be purchased, as design work can't be done in the runtime.